# Разъясните пожалуйста простым языком, действия происходящее в коде

Tags: java

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cat cat = new Cat();

        System.out.println(cat.name);
        changeName(cat);
        System.out.println(cat.name);
    }

    public static void changeName(Cat cat) {
        cat.name = "Jerry";
    }

    public static class Cat {        
        String name = "Tom";
    }
}
```

Comment: Создаем объект Cat, выводим в консоль его поле name, вызываем метод changeName в котором полю name класса Cat присваивается значение Jerry, опять печатаем его поле name.

Answer (score 2):

начинается всё с метода `main`, это входная точка, с которой начинается исполнение программы.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

затем создаётся объект класса `Cat` c именем `cat`

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
```

смотрим сам класс

```
 public static class Cat {        
        String name = "Tom";
    }
```

у класса имеется одно свойство, строковое поле под именем `name`, в которое сразу записывается значение `"Tom"`.

далее выводим в консоль значение поля `name` у ранее созданного объекта класса `Cat`

```
System.out.println(cat.name);
```

вызываем статический метод, который в параметры принимает любой объект класса `Сat` и меняем значение поля `name` на `"Jerry"`

```
 public static void changeName(Cat cat) {
        cat.name = "Jerry";
    }
```

ну и в конце выводим новое значение поля `name` объекта `cat`

```
System.out.println(cat.name);
```